# Refresh index stats in another schema

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Can I run DBMS_STATS.gather_index_stats on a index which is in another schema in oracle?

When I run gather_index_stats on index which is in another schema, it is showing an error "Privilege's are missing". So, is this facility available in Oracle? If yes, how can I achieve it?
Or is there any privilege's which I have to provide?

Thanks

Comment: @Littlefoot has given you a nice explanation of the proximate cause of the error.  I (as a retired DBA) would emphasize a couple of points. 1) the necessary privilege should not be granted lightly.  Why would anyone but a DBA or the schema owner need these privs?  I'd say "never".  Second, why do you think you need to manually gather stats on a specific index at all?  Oracle has a built in stats job that is sufficient for the vast majority of cases.  In my entire 25-years as an Oracle DBA, I rarely saw a justification for manually gather stats apart from Oracle's own job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can't do *anything* with other user's objects - you need to have privileges to do so.

I'm not a DBA and don't have any database to illustrate the "solution", so - unless someone explains it better - see if this helps.

In order to be able to work on someone else's objects, a privileged user - such as SYS (or any other which has DBA privileges) - should grant you one of `ANY` privilege (such as `alter any table`). "Any" means "owned by anyone", which also means that you can't be granted privilege to gather stats only for that "another" user you're talking about, but "any user" in the database.

System privileges are powerful so - think twice whether you should grant them to anyone.

I *think* (as I can't test it myself nor have I found it in documentation) that privilege you need is `ANALYZE ANY`.

- privileged user (SYS) should

  ```
  grant analyze any to you;
  ```
- connected as `you`, you'd then e.g.

  ```
  exec dbms_stats.gather_index_stats('SCOTT', 'PK_EMP');
  ```

  (where `SCOTT` represents that "other user" you're talking about)